# Split out interleaved log line into table with on cli

Tags: bash, awk, command-line-interface

Lets say I have some log lines that look something like:

```
"OUT 2019.11.05D04:51:39.583193000 ### hostname ### [blah] From 127.0.0.1 - Some Stuff here: ' Fred@somewhere.com, james@elsewhere.com, Steve@Cabbage.com, 75692, 45263, 99956, London, Sydney, Paris Some other Text ###"
```

The above has 3 elements that i want to turn into rows, but I dont know how many actual elements will be in it it so could be.

```
"OUT 2019.11.05D04:51:39.583193000 ### hostname ### [blah] From 127.0.0.1 - Some Stuff here: ' Fred@somewhere.com, james@elsewhere.com, Steve@Cabbage.com, Jane@doh.com, 75692, 45263, 99956, 22321, London, Sydney, Paris, Memphis Some other Text ###"
```

The above having 4 elements but that could be any number really up to about 30

And I'd like to turn thid into

```
Fred@somewhere.com  | 75692 | London
james@elsewhere.com | 45263 | Sydney
Steve@Cabbage.com   | 99956 | Paris
Jane@doh.com        | 99956 | Memphis
```

The cruft either side of the log line is always the same format and number of words, so can remove the first 13 words and the last 4. 
The number of resultant columns is static, 3 in the last example  but more in the real example.

I'd like a function I can pipe a tail of the log file into and output the resultant rows

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO we encourage users to post their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so kindly add so and let us know then.

Answer (score 0):

New solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

numCols=3
while IFS= read -r line
do
  CLEAN_INPUT=$(sed "s/.*'//; s/\([[:alpha:]]* \)\{3\}###$//" <<< $line)
  awk -F "," -v n=$numCols ' { for (i=1; i <= NF/n; i++) { print $(i),"|",$(i+NF/3),"|",$(i+2*NF/3) } }' <<< $CLEAN_INPUT
done < "input.txt
```

Edit: This will work only if INPUT is a single line:

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT="OUT 2019.11.05D04:51:39.583193000 ### hostname ### [blah] From 127.0.0.1 - Some Stuff here: ' Fred@somewhere.com, james@elsewhere.com, Steve@Cabbage.com, 75692, 45263, 99956, London, Sydney, Paris Some other Text ###"
CLEAN_INPUT=$(sed "s/.*'//; s/\([[:alpha:]]* \)\{3\}###$//" <<< $INPUT)
numCols=3
awk -F "," -v n=$numCols ' { for (i=1; i <= NF/n; i++) { print $(i),"|",$(i+NF/3),"|",$(i+2*NF/3) } }' <<< $CLEAN_INPUT
```

Can you try this?

This produces the desired output:

```
Fred@somewhere.com |  75692 |  London
 james@elsewhere.com |  45263 |  Sydney
 Steve@Cabbage.com |  99956 |  Paris
```

The alignment of your table in text format I leave as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

@stephanmg I got as far as this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#

read INPUT
CLEAN_INPUT=`echo $INPUT |  cut -d" " -f16- | rev | cut -d" " -f5- | rev | sed 's/ //g'`

#echo $INPUT
#echo $CLEAN_INPUT
numCols=12

# i is affectively row number
# j is the column number i want
# NF/n is the number of rows
# so the field i want at any point is identified as i + (j-1)*NF/n
awk -F "," -v n=$numCols ' { for (i=1; i <= NF/n; i++) { for (j=1; j <= n; j++) { printf $(i+((j-1)*NF/n))"|" } ;print ""}} ' <<< $CLEAN_INPUT
```

Which works but ends after one row when piped to this script :-(

Comment: You should edit your original post, not post an answer. See my edit above.